# Find Longest common Substring

Tags: c++

I need to find longest common substring from two DNA strings.
I have first string "CGATAC", and second: "GACAGTC"
With my code my result is: "GAC", but you can get longer substring, i mean "GATC". What i need to change to get longer substring ?

```cpp
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < substring1.length(); i++) {
    char znak = substring1[i];
    for (int j = k; j < substring2.length(); j++) {
        char znak2 = substring2[j];
        if (znak == znak2) {
            end_substring += znak;
            k = j;
            break;
        }
    }
}
cout << end_substring;
```

Comment: I have no idea how you came up with the answer of "GAC" as a common substring in the first string.  "GAC" appears in the second string, but not the first.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Based on OP's "longer substring" example, I think that the substring does not need to be contiguous.

Comment: This is asking for the [Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), a different problem than the title suggests.

Comment: And since this problem is well-documented, discussed, etc. an Internet search is all that's required to give a wealth of information.  As you can see, your code is just not going to do the job -- to solve it takes much more sophistication, again, discussed on many sites.

Comment: Yea i mean Subsequence. In polish dictionary "Substring" and "Subsequence" means this same. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

You can improve your code with some basic ideas. I understand you want **one** of the longest strings, not all, then you can store the length of the longest string until each moment in the program, and use this length for search string at least of length+1. But the bes solution is use dynamic porgramming, you can read this solution here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring-dp-29/